# PowerMockito with Spock: Unable to Mock classes from java.util.concurrent

Tags: java, groovy, mockito, spock, powermock

I need to mock **Executors** from **java.util.concurrent**. My Code is following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Sputnik.class)
@PrepareForTest([Executors.class, ClassThatCallsExecutors.class])
class WorkerManagerSpec extends Specification {
ExecutorService executorService
def "...."() {
        when:"...."
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(Executors.class)
 PowerMockito.when(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)).thenReturn(executorService)
    }
}
```

but I am getting following error for **power-mockito version 1.7.4**

```
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
> [Ljava.lang.Object;@6bea52d4 when() requires an argument which has to
> be 'a method call on a mock'.
```

Any way that can fix this issue? I am suspecting some dependency issue is there.

Comment: The need of mocking static methods is a sign, that there is something broken with your design. Take a few steps back and think if there is anything you could do to improve the design. You could try passing `ExecutorService` instance to the class constructor or even method parameter.